# Creating a sam canary deployment with aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-sam, infrastructure-as-code

I'm looking to take advantage of rolling canary deploy using aws sam (find the example [here][1]).  I don't want to drop a deployment on all my customers at once, and I want to be able to perform validation before it serves traffic, and I want automatic rollback on alarms going off.  If I was writing the sam template myself (rather than using the cdk to synthesize it), it would look like this:

```
Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      CodeUri: s3://bucket/code.zip

      AutoPublishAlias: live

      DeploymentPreference:
        Type: Canary10Percent10Minutes 
        Alarms:
          - !Ref AliasErrorMetricGreaterThanZeroAlarm
          - !Ref LatestVersionErrorMetricGreaterThanZeroAlarm
        Hooks:
          PreTraffic: !Ref PreTrafficLambdaFunction
          PostTraffic: !Ref PostTrafficLambdaFunction
```

Now I am trying to do this with the aws cdk (trying with java right now, since that's the language I am most comfortable with, but I am open to examples in other languages as well), but I cannot find the right options to do this.  Can anyone please give me an example to generate this using the cdk?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CfnFunction.DeploymentPreferenceProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/services/sam/DeploymentPreferenceProperty.html) -- seems like this is the class you want, if anyone else is looking (comes from sam dependency)